# Merge not working when using condtion of rowid in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a `person` table as:

[image]

I have another table `temp_person`

[image]

I want to merge the data of temp_person to person table when their `rowid` matches.So,I tried:

```
MERGE INTO OT.person A
USING OT.TEMP_person B
ON (A.rowid=B.rowid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.age=B.age
```

But it says:

```
0 rows merged.
```

Why are the rows not being merged?

Comment: `RowId` is a PseudoColumn of Oracle and should never Match if the record is not the same what is trivially true for 2 different tables. Do you want to merge based on column `ID` instead?

Comment: isnt it possible to merge by rowid?

Comment: No, It is not possible. Rowids can not be same for any row in entire DB. It is unique for each row

Comment: No. A rowid uniquely identifies one row of one table. So `(A.rowid=B.rowid)` can never be true (unless `A` and `B` are aliases for the same table).

Comment: If you can share the expected output then we would be able to help you

Comment: Why don't you MERGE on ID instead? That looks like a good candidate.